# "Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'"

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I am trying to create an expression of the following form:

```
f => f.Number;
```

when I try to create the expression:

```
var _sourceParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Organisation));
var propertyReference = Expression.Property(_sourceParameter, "Number");
var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Organisation, object>>(propertyReference, _sourceParameter);
```

I get the following exception:

```
Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'
```

how can I make this happen?

Comment: Could you change the return type from `object` to `int`? Or cast the `int` manually into `object` in the lambda expression? Unfortunately, due to the representation-changing nature of the implicit conversion of structs to `object`, C# doesn't allow generic variance between them.

Comment: The duplicate is correct, but it's weirdly verbose. You just need the generated Expression to cast int to object. So add a step that does that: `var castPropertyReference = Expression.Convert(propertyReference, typeof(Object));
var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Organisation, object>>(castPropertyReference, _sourceParameter);`

Comment: works like a charm. I'd gladly see this as the correct answer rather than the referenced one.

Comment: @hikizume Thanks. Can't add an answer after it's been closed though.